# Python 3 - tkinter , after() using float

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

Inside a loop, I will open my window several times and I want to close it, each time after a random value between  1,75 to 2,25 s.
I have tried this :

```
from tkinter import *
from random import *


root = Tk()
root.title('Temps inter-essai') 
root.config(bg='black')
larg_ecr, haut_ecr = root.winfo_screenwidth(), root.winfo_screenheight()
larg_can, haut_can = larg_ecr/4, haut_ecr/4

txt = str(larg_ecr) + "x" + str(haut_ecr)
root.geometry(txt)

temp=uniform(1.7,2.2)
root.after(temp,root.destroy)  
root.mainloop()
```

When I run , python says : 
"  return self.tk.call('after', ms, name)
_tkinter.TclError: bad argument "2.992766043938505": must be cancel, idle, info, or an integer"

Do you have an idea to fix this ? 
Thanks !!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`after()` takes time in milliseconds, not seconds.  You need to scale the value in addition to converting it to an integer:

```
root.after(int(temp * 1000), root.destroy)
```